# SubSonic 3 Install Question?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm eagerly about to install SubSonic 3 and start using it with one of my sites, but I'm already confused right at the beginning!?

The install instruction states

*Grab the folder containing the T4 templates (the "tt" extensions) **and locate the one that named "_Settings"**. Open it up in Notepad and set the value for "ConnectionStringName" to the name of the connection string you just made.*

I have downloaded it and cannot find a file called **"_Settings"** anywhere in the zip file???  Am I missing something or just being a complete plank??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a Settings.ttinclude file